# add checkboxes to multiple columns?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim MyLeft As Double
Dim MyTop As Double
Dim MyHeight As Double
Dim MyWidth As Double
dim emptyRow as long

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + ActiveSheet.Checkboxes.count
    MyLeft = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Left
    MyTop = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Top
    MyHeight = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Height
    MyWidth = MyHeight = Cells(emptyRow, 1).Width

   If CheckBox1.Value = True Then

     ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
     With Selection
        .Caption = ""

     End With
  End If
 End Sub
```

I have the following code, but is there a way to make checkboxes to different columns depending on which checkboxes are clicked? so, if checkbox 1 is clicked, then it would make a checkbox with a checkmark in column 1, and if checkbox 2 is clicked, then it would make a checkbox with a checkmark in column 2, and if no checkboxes are clicked, it would make checkboxes that are unchecked. i have 8 checkboxes - is there a better way to do it instead of putting multiple if statements?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution might be to add all the checkboxes, but use the .visible flag to determine whether or not they should be shown to the user. Also, rather than write code for each checkbox, have a single "ValidateCheckboxes" routine that covers them all, and call it from the click event for each checkbox.

I've pulled together some code that does this for all the checkboxes on the activesheet. Just add them to your screen in ascending order, and this code should hide all but the last empty tickbox.

```
Sub ValidateCheckBoxes()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

With ActiveSheet
For i = 1 To .CheckBoxes.Count - 1

    Debug.Print .CheckBoxes(i).Caption
    Debug.Print .CheckBoxes(i).Value

    If .CheckBoxes(i).Value <> 1 Then
        .CheckBoxes(i + 1).Visible = False
    Else
        If .CheckBoxes(i).Visible = False Then
            .CheckBoxes(i + 1).Visible = False
        Else
            If Not .CheckBoxes(i + 1).Visible = True Then
                'show the next checkbox
                .CheckBoxes(i + 1).Visible = True
                'set its value to false
                .CheckBoxes(i + 1).Value = -4146
                'hide all the remaining check boxes
                For j = i + 2 To .CheckBoxes.Count
                    .CheckBoxes(j).Visible = False
                Next j
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i
End With
End Sub
```